# How to make bulk asynchronous API calls in batches in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asynchronous

I have an array of GET APIs which needs to be asynchronously called in batches and responses to be stored in another array.
For example if i have 230 APIs in an array and my batch size is 50, i have to make 50 service calls per batch for four times and the last batch needs to make 30 service calls. The new batch of service calls should be executed when the previous batch APIs have completed processing.

Comment: Do they need to be in batches or can there just be a limit of 50 on the number of ongoing requests at any given time?

Comment: Use `$q.all` to wait for an array of promises. See [AngularJS $q Service API Reference -- $q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all).